# View is not loading after login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

In my laravel project i have a login system from another table named agencie. Login functionality is working but view page is returning `'404 error'`.

Following is my code in Logincontroller.php

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Agency\AgencyAuth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Hesto\MultiAuth\Traits\LogsoutGuard;
    use JsValidator;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */

        use AuthenticatesUsers, LogsoutGuard {
            LogsoutGuard::logout insteadof AuthenticatesUsers;
        }

        protected $validationRules = [
                                            'email' => 'required|email',
                                            'password' => 'required'
                                        ];

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        public $redirectTo = '/agencie/home';

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('agencie.guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
        }

        /**
         * Show the application's login form.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function showLoginForm()
        {
            $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules,[],[],'#loginform');
            return view('agency.auth.login')->with('validator', $validator);
        }

        /**
         * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
         */
        protected function guard()
        {
            return Auth::guard('agencie');
        }

        public function logoutToPath() {
            return '/agencie';
        }
    }
```

I have created custom roots for agencie to load that, foolowing is the codes in routes/agencie.php

```
<?php
Route::get('/home', function () {
    $users[] = Auth::user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard()->user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard('agencie')->user();

    //dd($users);
    // echo "<pre>";print_r($users);exit;

    // return view('admin.home');
    return redirect()->route('agencie.home');
})->name('home');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'agencie'], function () {
        Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('agency_home');
    });

    ?>
```

Following is the code in homecontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


    class HomeController extends Controller
    {

        public function index()
        {
            echo "agency page";
        }

    }
```

What is the problem here why it is not laoding?

Comment: `agencie/home` is not the same as `agency/home` (your prefix in the route)

Comment: I have corrected it and its not working

Comment: On the command line, run `php artisan route:list`, and compare what's listed to the URL in your browser. Edit:: route, not routes

Comment: Make sure your routes are not cached with that old, incorrect value.

Comment: To avoid confusion with urls/prefixes/routes: you already named your route (`->name('agency_home')`), I suggest you use the named route instead of manually posting/changing urls. You can change `public $redirectTo = '/agencie/home';` to `public $redirectTo = route('agency_home');` and never again have to worry about the actual url. You can/should also change `return redirect()->route('agencie.home');` to `return redirect()->route('agencie_home');` assuming there is no route named `agencie.home`

Comment: @kerbholz Except you need static values for class variable declarations, so `public $redirectTo = route('agency_home');` won't work. It can be done within a `__construct()` method, though.

Comment: Can u pls show an example

Comment: @aynber You're right, what was I thinking? Thanks for noticing. Scratch that `public $redirectTo = route('agency_home');` part, my fault

Comment: @aynber can you pls show it as code

Comment: You already have a __construct() method, so in there, just add `$this->redirectTo = route('agency_home');`

Answer (score 0):

```php
public $redirectTo = '/agencie/home';
```

Doesn't seem to match:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'agency'], /*...*/);
```

Comment: i have changed that prefix from 'agency' to 'agencie'

Comment: Does the `/agencie/home` URL work when you try it in the browser?

Comment: Then you probably have the routes cached. Try `php artisan route:list` as someone mentioned before. Also, you never want to `echo` in Laravel Controllers. You want to return a response.

Comment: actually am unable to acces terminal?Is there is anyway to clear rote cache via laravel code

Comment: Now also page is not accesable,its returning 404 error

Comment: But if i provide this in web.php it is producing "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." error

Comment: Oh, I thought it was in web.php. If you create custom routes file, you need to manually load it via RouteServiceProvider.

Comment: Then why it is not laoding , if it is in web.php , it producing "Whoops, looks like something went wrong" error, Not only that i have created seperate route because i want to access logined user id and make operations on that

Comment: Your Laravel app doesn't know anything about your `routes/agencie.php` file. And you need to debug that error that you see when you use your route properly. It's all there on the screen.